Combinatorial proof for $2^n$
If $n \geqslant 1$, then prove that, for $n$  odd,
$$ 2^n = \binom{n+1}{1} + \binom{n+1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n+1}{n} $$
and for $n$ even
$$ 2^n = \binom{n+1}{1} + \binom{n+1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n+1}{n+1} $$
I can think of a set of size $n$ and I know that number of subsets of a set are $2^n$. But I don't know how to get right hand sides.
Thanks

Maybe , it is better to consider a set of size $n+1$ and the equations multiplied with $2$.

This question is similar to: Combinatorial proof for $\sum_{r=0} {n \choose {2r}} = \sum_{r=0} {n \choose {2r+1}} = 2^{n-1}$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (Found using Approach$0$ https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%30site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Cbinom%20n%7B2k%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3ACombinatorial&p=1)

$${n+1\choose r}={n\choose r}+{n\choose  r-1}$$ for all $r$.

@Gerry , nice trick. And Anne, yes it does answer my question. Thanks

Ok, I want to post my answer. Consider a set of cardinality $n+1$. So, let $S = \{1,2,3,\cdots,n,n+1 \} $. Now, first consider $n+1$ to be odd. Now, we count number of subsets of $S$ which have odd number of elements. This would be
$$ \binom{n+1}{1} + \binom{n+1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n+1}{n+1} \;\;\cdots (1) $$
Next, if we take a subset with odd number of elements and take a symmetric difference with $\{1\}$, then we get a subset with even number of elements. For example, take $\{1,2,3 \} $. After taking symmetric difference with $\{1\}$, we get $\{2,3\}$. So, number of subsets with odd number of elements is same as number of elements with even number of elements. This can also be seen from binomial theorem
$$ 0 = (1-1)^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^k \binom{n+1}{k} $$
$$ \binom{n+1}{1} + \binom{n+1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n+1}{n+1} = \binom{n+1}{0} + \binom{n+1}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n+1}{n} $$
Also from binomial theorem, we see that
$$ 2^{n+1} = (1+1)^{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} $$
From this, we can deduce that
$$ \binom{n+1}{1} + \binom{n+1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{n+1}{n+1}  = 2^{n+1}/2 = 2^n $$
Similar argument can be given if $n+1$ is even.
